# Implement reference key in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a TestPack table that can have n no of Lines associated with it. But a Line may exist without a TestPack. Later on, a Line might be assigned a TestPack#.

What this relationship is called and how do I implement this relationship in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Is a single line only ever attached to _one_ particular test pack or can a single line record be included in many TestPacks?

Comment: I will have to confirm the requirements but my guess is that a line will be attached to a single test pack. Can u guide me about both possibilities?

Comment: a line will always be against a single TestPack record but the test pack might not exist at the time Line was added to db. (confirmed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a "one-to-zero-or-one" relationship, as one Line might be associated to zero or one TestPacks.

You can implement it by using a FK that allows NULL values.

```
CREATE TABLE TestPack (id INT,
                       PRIMARY KEY (id))

CREATE TABLE Line (id INT, 
                   TestPackId INT NULL,
                   FOREIGN KEY (TestPackId) REFERENCES TestPack(id))
```

By making the "TestPackId" column in "Line" table to allow NULL values, you can have a Line with no TestPack (inserting a NULL there), and then assiging a TestPack by setting the id of the corresponding TestPack later.

Comment: Now I m getting this error message on  he insert statement after allowing nulls in the test_pack_id (which is the foreign key)
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_Line_TestPack\". The conflict occurred in database \"TPM\", table \"dbo.TestPack\", column 'id'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.

Comment: Are you inserting a NULL in the TestPackId field? Or are you inserting an actual value there? If you are inserting an actual value, then you have to make sure that id also exists in the TestPack table.

Comment: no, as I said a test Pack might now exist when a Line is added. later on a test pack might arrive and we add it to the database.

Comment: oh ic. actually test_pack_id was assigned a default value 0 because its non nullable

Comment: It has not yet been confirmed if a line can belong to 0,1, or _many_ TestPack records

Comment: OK it has been confirmed that a line can belong to only 0 or 1 TestPack records, meaning this answer is correct